# Local host XAMPP doesn't keep track file changes

Tags: javascript, xampp

I had tried the different solutions but XAMPP doesn't keep track of my js file. I had cleared the browser's cache and quitted the XAMPP and then restart it again. In spite of all this, when I made some changes in the js files those changes weren't reflected in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to it, but it is done manually. First, make changes in your files and save the changes. After you are done with your changes, close your file. And now, if you start your Xammp server, it will consider your changes. But keep in my while making any change in files Xammp server must not be active.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution. I have found that if I load the web page in the incognito mode, the changes in the code are reflected. Judging from this behavior, the problem is not with XAMPP. Instead, I think the browser is keeping the web page in cache which makes it load from the cache which is the older version of the web page. As Incognito doesn't store any data, the browser has to load the latest updated version of the web page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).